# Spring JMS message converters with extended messages classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

Using Spring boot 1.5.9 and JMS 2.0.1 with Java 9.0.....

Talking with IBM's MQ (version 9) with their `MQQueueConnectionFactory` which delivers to an `@JmsListener` an `com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage` that extends the `javax.jms.Message` class.  This means the normal type reflection by a `MessageConverter` isn't used.  Not sure where in the Spring JMS pipeline I can transform the JMSMessage into a normal Message and then activate conversion?  When testing I would like to use an embedded active mq that produces `Message` objects not `JMSMessage`.

Thus it would be great if the annotated receiver method accepted `Message` not `JMSMessage`.

## Update 1

The following signature has to be used otherwise the Spring pipeline fails with no defined MessageConverter for a IBM `JMSMessage`:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${mq.queue}")
public void receive(
  JMSMessage message,
  @Header(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId
) ... {
   ....
}
```

I want to have a signature that looks like:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${mq.queue}")
public void receive(
  Message message,
  @Header(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId
) ... {
   ....
}
```

Otherwise, when testing (with an embedded jms queue manager) the receiving method doesn't have a consistent signature.  Must exist a spot in the Spring JMS pipeline (e.g. MessageListener) where I can intercept the `JMSMessage`, pull out it's delegate `Message` and send that onto the `JmsListener`.

## Update 2

False alarm.  Redid tests with a live configuration and a receive signature that accepts a plain `java.jmx.Message` and just as **M.D.** pointed out it worked.  As well, the default simple message converter that uses the ClassUtils to turn the underlying JMSTextMessage into a string.

Comment: ActiveMQ will also produce a JMS based message (generally). The JMS listener should also be able to accept a regular `Message` instead of the `javax.jms.Message` and it will do the conversion accordingly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Problem isn't ActiveMQ rather IBM that passes around it's flavor of the `java.jmx.Message` which is what I would like to catch prior to it hitting the receiver method (and transform the JMSMessage into a Message).

Comment: Your question is unclear on what you want to achieve. You can simply use `Message` as an argument instead of the `javax.jms.Message`. If that doesn't apply to your use-case rewrite your question as it then is unclear what you want to ask.

Comment: @M.Deinum See update 1.

Comment: Which `Message` are you using here? As stated as the IBM classes extend the normal JMS interfaces that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @M.Deinum False alarm.  But thanks for the help.